# Unable to remove php7.2-fpm from Ubuntu on boot

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, boot, php-7.2, deb, fpm

I would like to remove `php7.2-fpm` from on boot start because `Supervisor` process manager will take care of starting `php7.2-fpm`. Do do this I had tried following commands but none of them worked for me. Ubuntu version is `14.04`.

```
> sudo update-rc.d php7.2-fpm remove
    Output: update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm exists during rc.d purge (use -f to force)

> sudo update-rc.d -f php7.2-fpm remove
    Output: Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm ...

> sudo update-rc.d php7.2-fpm disable
    Output: update-rc.d: warning:  start runlevel arguments (none) do not match php7.2-fpm Default-Start values (2 3 4 5)
update-rc.d: warning:  stop runlevel arguments (none) do not match php7.2-fpm Default-Stop values (0 1 6)
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm do not exist.

> ls -al /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm
  Output: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4793 Jan 13 10:58 /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm
```

I'm not getting what's wrong in my commands.

Comment: `sudo rm /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm` ?

Comment: @emix is it proper approach? can we restore in future if we issue your command?

Comment: `update-rc.d` is just a simple script which creates or removes scripts inside `/etc/init.d`. You would have to manually remove related files from the `/etc/rcX` directories as well. You can temporarily disable this service too `sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm`

Answer (score 2):

Disable the service in case you need it in the future:

```
# prevent the script from being executed
sudo chmod -x /etc/init.d/php7.2-fpm
```

Comment: php7.2-fpm service is required but it's via a supervisor process manager